# How to use drupal_get_token() within custom user registration email

Tags: users, tokens

I'm in the process of writing a custom user registration module for Drupal 7. I currently have my own custom form which calls the function **user_save** within it's submit handler to create the new user account. The account is initially created as "disabled", and will only be activated once the user verified their account via a link in a custom welcome email.

I have generated a token to append to the URL query string (contained in the email generated by **hook_mail()** using **drupal_get_token()**):

```
$myToken = drupal_get_token('email_verify_'.$params->uid);
```

Unfortunately I'm always getting an Access Denied message when following the registration link within my custom email. I've checked both values storing the UID within the hook_mail and page callback and they're indeed correct.

Is there anything I'm missing here? I considered using **user_pass_reset_url()** instead, but we capture the user password on registration so we don't want them to have to re-enter their password twice.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT #2: adding more code for Pontus**

hook_menu implementation:

```
//callback to verify user via email link
$items['custom_user/signup/verify/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Activate your Account',
  'page callback' => 'customer_user_signup_verify_email_page',
  'page arguments' => array(3),
  'file' => 'includes/custom_user_signup.verify.inc',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Check if valid token within **customer_user_signup_verify_email_page()** callback function  **drupal_valid_token():**

```
if (empty($_GET['tok']) || !drupal_valid_token($_GET['tok'], 'email_verify_' . $user_id)) {
    drupal_access_denied();
}else{
    //enable account now that we know you're a valid user
}
```

URL printed in email:

```
http://mysite.com/custom_user/signup/verify/10?tok=Zh2MmBHLnjvd3Dq9KcDxkwJ0lmk_QmMg5QNZomC7Okw
```

Comment: What's the URL to your page callback? Could you post more code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please see my editted post for the callback URL and email URL. I just double checked to make sure that the UID arg is coming through correctly in hook_mail and my page callback, and they're both matching.

Comment: I've had a closer look at the function drupal_valid_token(), and it seems to use the SESSION ID to see whether a token is valid or not. Would opening the email containing the link create a completely new session? If it does this might be why the tokens are mis matching.

Comment: Could you post the whole implementation of your hook_menu? What does your access argument / access callback say?

Comment: added the full hook_menu implementation for you. The access arguments are 'access content' to allow any anonymous user to use this route (tested and working). I then check if the token is valid within the callback to make sure the link is being visited via the email link. thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is failing is because [`drupal_get_token()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_token/7) and [`drupal_valid_token()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_valid_token/7) use the value of [`session_id()`](https://www.php.net/session_id) to generate and validate the token.

The problem is that `session_id()` will return a different value for anonymous users on each page load. So the token generated by `drupal_valid_token()` is different from the one that is generated in `drupal_get_token()` because the input (`sessoin_id()`) is different.

For form submits where you want to compare a token on the next page load for anonymous users, you can call [`drupal_session_start()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21session.inc/function/drupal_session_start/7) on the form page which will start a session and ensure that the results of `session_id()` are the same on the form page and the result page. But in your case, where the user is clicking on a link back to the site from an email, the value of `session_id()` will only be the same if it's the exact next page load. My tests indicate that Drupal destroys the session created by `drupal_session_start()` on the next page load.

Comment: I ended up creating a module for this: [Anonymous Tokens](https://github.com/balsama/anontoken). It is dependent on a little helper module, [Universally Unique User ID](https://github.com/balsama/uuuid).

Comment: Also check out the [Sessions API](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_api) module for help with anonymous user sessions.