# Sending Email verification when registering programmatically

Tags: 7, users, emails

I have created multi-step form through custom module. I am `using user_save()` function to register the user and `user_mail_notify()` to send the email.

Now I am not sure what should I send in `_user_mail_notify()` so email verification link will work.

I have account settings in the backend as shown in screenshot

[image]

and sending **op** value as '**register_no_approval_required**' in `_user_mail_notify()` function. I am receiving verification email in inbox but when I click it then it doesn't work.

However it works when we register through default registration form. Please let me know if anything I am missing to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new account using "user_save()", What status you passed "0" or "1", If you required email verification then it should be 'status' => 0, in user_save().

Comment: Yes, I am passing status as '0' so user will remain as blocked till the time user hasn't verified email. But after clicking on it, it just say access denied however it should log me in with email verified message.

Comment: You can refer this answer posted by "[Omar](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/15442/28683)"

Comment: OK thanks, I have allowed users to set their password at the form.  So checking this reference link I can see that I need to send a custom link and a custom verification page where it will be validated. But don't you think this email will not work like default that shows you have already used this link.
Also any good reference link to create that custom email verification page.

Comment: Hmmm, It will not work like default mail. Looking for some other best way If I get any success will update here.

Comment: For custom email verification you can do something like "[This](http://www.beyondspotsanddots.com/creating-alternate-user-email-verification-system-drupal)"

Comment: This is some what related to you "[Custom user registration](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80738/how-to-use-drupal-get-token-within-custom-user-registration-email)"

Comment: did you tried with pass [one time login] token value

Comment: default registration used [one time login] token

Answer (score -2):

Solved, My problem are email service on server.

Now I use smpt (https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp)

It's ok.